# Remove quotes from JSON file

Tags: python, json, regex, string

I receive a JSON file structured in a similar manner:

```
{"Value1" : "1", "Value2" : "2", "Value3" : "3"},
{"Value4" : "4", "Value5" : "5", "Value5" : "5"}
```

Unfortunately, I do not have control over how this JSON is parsed.  Consequently, I am needing the quotes removed so the integers are not treated as strings, as such:

```
{"Value1" : 1, "Value2" : 2, "Value3" : 3},
{"Value4" : 4, "Value5" : 5, "Value5" : 5}
```

I feel this can be achieved with regular expressions (albeit it might be a bit "dirty"), but am not sure how to go about doing this.  Any suggestions?
Edit: All values are integers within the JSON file.

Comment: Are all values integers? And **don't** use regular expressions, use the `json` module.

Comment: Reut, yes they are all integers.

Comment: use `int()` function at the values

Comment: ProgrammerGuy, it's on the back end via linux.

Comment: @icehac is this a json per-line file or a json list file (does it start with `{{`)?

Comment: Reut, it does not start with {{.  Each line is delimited with a comma, which I had forgot to state earlier, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm all for doing things properly, but parsing a JSON file with json, converting and round-tripping without explicit knowledge of its structure sounds like a mess. So here's the quick-and-dirty regexp solution you were after:

```
import re
with open("data.json") as inp:
    lines = inp.readlines()

with open("clean.json", "w") as output:
    for line in lines:
        output.write(re.sub(r'"(\d+)"', r"\1", line))
```

Comment: Alright @alexis, I hate to bug you again...what about handling floats as well? :)

Comment: You can match either a dot or a digit with `[\d.]`. But now you're running the risk of unquoting things like `"3.4.02", ".", "1...10"` etc. It all depends on what your data really contains. Try to think through your questions better...

Comment: for instance, the value "2500.25" is still quoted with the given RE.  All floats found within the specific json will have a similar sructure (xxxx.yy).

Answer (score 1):

Solution code:

```
import json

inputstr = (...)

data = json.loads(inputstr)
for (key, val) in data.items():
    data[key] = int(val)

outputstr = json.dumps(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about loading each line using the `json` module?

```
import json
with open("input-file.json") as json_input_file:
    for line in json_input_file:
        # remove end of line comma (avoid removing in last line)
        if line.endswith(','):
            line = line[:-1]
        # parse values to ints
        line_json = {k: int(v) for k, v in json.loads(line).items()}
        # do something with json
        print line_json
```

If you want to write a result file:

```
import json
with open("input-file.json") as json_input_file:
    with open("result-file.json", 'w+') as json_file_result:
        for line in json_input_file:
            # remove end of line comma (avoid removing in last line)
            if line.endswith(','):
                line = line[:-1]
            # parse values to ints
            line_json = {k: int(v) for k, v in json.loads(line).items()}
            # do something with json
            json_file_result.write(json.dumps(json_line) + "\n")
```

This will produce the file `result-file.json`:

```
{"Value3": 3, "Value2": 2, "Value1": 1}
{"Value5": 5, "Value4": 4}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong Reut.  I'm receiving this error running your script: "ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 205 - line 2 column 1 (char 204 - 206)"

Comment: Probably because there is a comma at the end of each line... parsing JSON one line at a time doesn't strike me as the best idea.

Comment: @alexis Ahh, you're right, I thought this is a json-in-a-line format. Thanks. Will edit according to further info from OP.

Comment: Now you've *removed* the commas. How is this better than using a regexp?

Comment: In my experience regular expressions are almost unmaintainable, and have the property of becoming increasingly unmaintainable when maintained.